# Getting Rubytest to work with MacVim

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim

I am trying to get Rubytest.vim to work with my Macvim installation.

I have dropped the rubytest.vim script to ~/.vim/plugin folder.

I had to remap the keys that rubytest uses from \t to \r due to conflicts with other mappings.

On trying the run a single test with \r, Macvim shows the text

```
 :call SNR<82>_Run(1)
```

at the bottom and nothing else happens.

Not sure what is going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have forgotten the `<CR>` at the end of your remapping, so the mapping is incomplete and waits for input in the command-line.